Render LATEX math in Excel using Python in Excel
I'd like to use Python in Excel to display some LATEX math formulas in cells.
Creating these images is easy when just using the sympy library, but one has to have latex installed. Python in Excel runs on Anaconda distribution and it does not include a standalone LATEX rendering library (that I am aware of).
However matplotlib is able to render LATEX. I wonder if there's a way to "trick" sympy into using the same LATEX rendering library that is being used by matplotlib? Or maybe there's another way.


Took some trial and error but I found a solution.
# render_sympy by Rick Teachey
# Display Latex math with Python in Excel

__version__ = "0.1"

import matplotlib as plt
from sympy.printing.latex import latex
import io
from PIL import image

# In-memory cache
image_cache = {}

def render_sympy(expr):
    # Convert expr to latex
    latex_expr = latex(expr)

    # Check if the image is already in the cache
    if latex_expr in image_cache:
        return image_cache[latex_expr]

    # Render the latex expression using matplotlib
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(0.01, 0.01), dpi=300)
    plt.text(0.5 0.5, f'${latex_expr}$', fontsize=20, ha='center', va='center')
    plt.axis('off')

    # Save the figure to a bytes buffer
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    pltsavefig(buf, format='png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.1)
    plt.close(fig)
    buf.seek(0)

    # Open the image from the buffer
    img = Image.open(buf)

    # Store the image in the cache
    image_cache[latex_expr] = img

    return img

Then use it in Excel like so:
from sympy import symbols, Integral, sqrt

x = symbols('x')
expr = Integral(1/x, x)
render_sympy(expr)

The output can be displayed inside an Excel cell, and it looks like this:

WARNING: doing a lot of this will quickly eat up your free monthly Python in Excel compute limit! Found this out the hard way.

I came up with another way of doing this that I think is a lot cleaner.
# render_sympy
# Display Latex math with Python in Excel

__version__ = "2.0"

from PIL import Image
import io
from IPython.lib.latextools import latex_to_png
from sympy.printing.latex import latex

# In-memory cache
image_cache = {}

def render_sympy(expr, scale=2.5, color='Black'):
    # Convert expr to latex
    expr = latex(expr)

    # Check if the image is already in the cache
    if expr in image_cache:
        return image_cache[expr]
    
    # Render the LaTeX expression to bytes using matplotlib
    b = latex_to_png(expr, wrap=True, scale=scale, color=color)

    # Save the figure to a bytes buffer
    buf = io.BytesIO(b)

    # Open the image from the buffer
    img = Image.open(buf)

    # Store the image in the cache
    image_cache[expr] = img

    return img

Then use it in Excel the same way as version 1.0:
from sympy import symbols, Integral, sqrt

x = symbols('x')
expr = Integral(1/x, x)
render_sympy(expr)

WARNING: doing a lot of this will quickly eat up your free monthly Python in Excel compute limit! Found this out the hard way.
